# parse error using esprima for file while optimizing js files with r.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I am optimizing several js files into one using `r.js`. It works fine before. Recently,I modified some js code, add the code as:

```
var x = 08;
```

then it shows

> ERROR:parse error using esprima for file D://webroot/js/a.js
>
> ERROR:line 45: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

Line 45 is where I add `var x = 08`, and `09` will show error too. It seemed that numbers begining with 0 meanwhile containing `8` or `9` is illegal. Maybe they were treated as bese 8 number .. ?

How can I let `r.js` ignore this point and still optimizie js files?

Comment: Looks like a (minor) bug in r.js, you could try reporting it on [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues?milestone=12&page=1&state=open). Why are you prefixing numbers with zeros, though? The simplest fix would be not to do that...

Answer (score 15):

i had the same problem

Turn out that it was just a double comma while requiring files.
Ex

```
define([
 'file1',
 'file2',
 'file3',,
 'file4'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This fixed it for me! Stared at the file way too long without even noticing, till I read this! Thanks!

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I spent so many hours until I found your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The error is due to Esprima, which `r.js` uses internally. To replicate the problem, you can go to [this page](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html) and type in `var x = 08;`

Generally speaking, it seems that JavaScript interpreters will treat a number with a leading zero that **can** be interpreted as an octal number as an octal number but if it cannot be interpreted as an octal number (e.g. 08), then they will treat it as decimal.

I've done a test with Node.js and got this:

```
$ node
> 07
7
> 08
8
> 09
9
> 010
8
>
```

And for even more fun:

```
> (function () {'use strict'; var x = 08;})()
undefined
> (function () {'use strict'; var x = 012;})()
SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
[ ... traceback deleted ...]
```

When strict mode is on, octals are illegal.

I would avoid octals and never prefix any number with zeros in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error when i forgot the question mark on my one-line if statement, inside a require js module.

Wrong line:

```
var check = self.currentScroll() > self.lastScroll() ? 1 : self.currentScroll() < self.lastScroll() -1 : 0
```

Corrected :

```
var check = self.currentScroll() > self.lastScroll() ? 1 : self.currentScroll() < self.lastScroll() ? -1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, while parsing a very long string:

```
var styleHTML = "<style>....</style>"
```

It turns out that in the string I also included some comments like this：

```
/* ... */
```

When I delete all the **css comments** in the string, it works!

Hope this helps.